# A quirky issue with Guake

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake

I have installed Guake and it works fine on my system. However here is a small issue that drives me crazy.

I have configured Guake to start on startup and I use`F-12` to invoke it. So the first time I use `F-12` the first line should be my prompt-`$` . Instead I see two lines - the additional output of pressing `<CR>`.

More precisely, I get something like

```
$
$
```

instead of the expected

```
$.
```

For every instance of pressing `F-12` Guake seems to adding an extra `<CR>`. If I have multiple tabs open this happens across all tabs. I fiddled unsuccessfully with Guake preference settings but couldn't solve this issue. All other Guake functionality is fine.

The reason I think this is an Guake issue not my shell configuration is because I do not notice this behaviour with other terminals.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Consider filing bug report to the developers. Also, is your input method english ? Try running guake from command line with `LC_ALL=C guake` command

Comment: Thanks. Yes my input method is english.  I did the `LC_ALL=C` command but the same problem persists.